Wayland API for getting screenshots and window titles
In x11 sessions you can take screenshots, get the current window's title, etc. via the xcb/xlib library API. How to do the same for wayland sessions? I would like to see some examples in C/C++
Ubuntu 22, Gnome


-> https://stackoverflow.com/ 2. Screenshots: https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/blob/main/data/org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot.xml 3. No idea what you meant by "window titles".

